# C# получить данные с сайта с авторизацией

Tags: c#, авторизация

у меня есть учетка на неком сайте. там выполняется аякс запрос типа script.php?data=somedata и возвращается JSON. хочу выполнить подобный запрос из программы, но получаю 401 неавторизованный доступ. как выполнить авторизацию из программы с моей учеткой?

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
string resp = wc.DownloadString(queryString);
```

больше кода нет, потому что не знаю как выполнить авторизацию

Comment: ну как, на неком сайте выполнить некий запрос авторизации получить некие данные авторизации и передать их с интересующим запросом.PS: Как описали задачу, так и советую. Вопрос слишком общий

Comment: Покажите код, то что вы смогли сделать. Чтобы людям было от чего отталкиваться.

Comment: Что за сайт? Напишите адрес сайта!